# File syncronization program for a PHP developer

Tags: windows, linux, file, synchronization

I would like to synchronize my local PHP files and remote ones. I'm on Windows, the remote servers are Linux and Windows. Is there something (sync app) helpful for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into a versioning system instead so as to keep your production code and your development code seperate. This will allow you to store your project files in one centralized location, but still maintain independence between your versions. An added benefit is being able to view past project versions + branch your projects. I use [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), but there are other alternatives such as HG.